# How can we get deep link url from firebase dynamic link short url programmatically?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-url

I have QR code made by **firebase dynamic link (short URL)** which will redirect to the App Store/Play Store directly to download the app and read the **deep link query parameters** when launching the app for the first time. That works well as expected.

But, The situation is, if I scan the same QR code within the app, Simply I want **just query parameters passed in the deep-link URL or long URL** which contains all that I want.

Any inputs? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Actually I also experienced like your problem.
QR code reader can not parse query parameters passed in the deep-link long URL.

```
[Before]
http://xxx.page.link/?link=https://www.google.com/doodles/
```

But if you use url encoded parameter, QR code can read that long deep link.

```
[After]
http://xxx.page.link/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fdoodles%2F
```